# cann't get HTML completion in JS file in VS Code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm experiencing an issue with VS Code where I can't use the Tab key for code completion. I've checked the settings and ensured that code completion is enabled. I've also verified that I'm in the correct language mode. Do you have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this further?
eg. I can't get the code completion while writting '.details + enter/tab' (nothing change) like it worked in the HMTL file ()

How can I fix the problem? Hand writting code by code is quite slow.
Thanks all!

[the tutor's work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgBeV.png)

[my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSDD1.png)

Comment: You can't include HTML in a JS file but you can include JS in a HTML file. IMO code completion would be confusing. For example, comparing if a value is smaller than X, you start typing '<' and VS Code starts suggesting all kinds of HTML tags.. I would also suggest looking into JS template engines which makes combining JS and HTML way easier.